# IntelliJ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager during startup

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4 x64 and got following error message during application starting process:

> Internal error. Please report to
>   http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager
>       at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:225)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>       at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:36)
>       at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:79)

I already tried to remove IDE caches folder: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519.

Comment: Did you update IDEA? see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000421044-IntelliJ-Not-Launching-Post-Update-java-lang-ClassNotFoundException-com-intellij-ide-plugins-PluginManager-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your installation is corrupted, please [reinstall](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).

Comment: Isn't any chance to repair existing installation?

Comment: Download the .zip version and overwrite *.jar files in the existing installation. But it's almost the same as reinstalling.

Comment: Had this issue when updating to 2020.2, tried everything. Downgrade to 2020.1.4 helped.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps which i have tried

1. Clearing cache as per the intellij Website instructions --didn't worked
2. Clearing Temp files -- didn't worked
3. Use window system cleaner to remove...temp files..temp internet files..etc --- Worked.

Comment: How do you mean "window system cleaner"?

Comment: In the windows 10 search just type "Temp" It will give you the option of "Free disk space by cleaning unnecessary file". Select that option and go for c drive and then just select all the options which you think isn't required for you. After this step just start Intellij again. It worked for me in this way.